# Add variable to TSQL string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

This is my SQL command that works

```
SET @Command = 'REN "C:\Nielsen\' + @FileName + '" "'
+ RIGHT(@FileName,LEN(@FileName)-11) + '"'
```

I want to replace the `C:\Nielsen\` with the value from a variable called `@Nielsen`

This does not work.....what am I missing?

```
SET @Command = 'REN ' + @Nielsen + @FileName  
+ RIGHT(@FileName,LEN(@FileName)-11) + ''
```

**EDIT**

Error message is:

> *The syntax of the command is incorrect.*

Comment: Please define "does not work" - what did you expect, what do you see?

Comment: I am missing something because the error is The syntax of the command is incorrect.

Comment: Your first version has a space between `@Nielsen` and `@Filename`. Perhaps you need that in your second version as well?

Comment: @etienne - do you get the error on the `Set @Command` line, or when you execute the command you built (you are missing some `"` and spaces)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could break it down like below (Sorry formatting doesn't work properly due to escape characters):

```
--Same string without variable 
SET @Command = 'REN "' + 'C:\Nielsen\' + @FileName + '" "'
+ RIGHT(@FileName,LEN(@FileName)-11) + '"'

--Same string with variable 
SET @Command = 'REN "' + @Nielsen + @FileName + '" "'
+ RIGHT(@FileName,LEN(@FileName)-11) + '"'
```